# Error on submit form

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms

Why i can't insert on my database? This is my code

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$bdate = $_POST['bdate'];
$id = $_POST['id'];

if (!empty($name) && !empty($email)){
    mysql_query("insert into customer(id,name,email,bdate) values($id,'$name','$email','$bdate')");
}
else {
    echo "Please fill <strong>name</strong> and <strong>e-mail</strong> fields!";
}

?>
```

My form is

```
<form method="post" action="new_customer.php">
    ID: <input type="text" name="id" size="5" value="<?php echo $new_id; ?>" disabled="disabled" /><br />
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" size="50" /><br />
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" size="30" /><br />
    Birth Date: <input type="text" name="bdate" size="10" /><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

The var $new_id is filled with this query

```
SELECT (Max(id) + 1) as new_id FROM customer
```

But when I submit the form, the error i get is:

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in F:\UniServer\www\admin\customer.php on line 6
```

and then a mysql error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' '')' at line 1
```

i think the first error causes the secund, right?

Comment: What is id if it is your autoincreament id then remove it and try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because disabled fields are not present in `$_POST` array.
In your case make `id` field auto increment in the database and make a query without it:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO customer(name, email, bdate) values('$name', '$email', '$bdate')");
```

Also your code is subject to SQL injection - use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) before the query:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
```

Comment: It worked! I searched for auto increment, don't really know it. now i'll search for this SQL injection too. thank you man.

Answer (score 0):

remove " disabled="disabled"  " ...

This is stopping the form to post the field to your PHP.

Comment: Instead, you can use readonly="readonly" , this will make the field uneditable.

Comment: as I said, this will make the field uneditable, and user can't enter any value.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the code of mysql that is fetching records, as there might be an error in assignment of table id value to php value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `disabled="disabled"` you want to use `readonly="readonly"`. This prevents the field from being edited, but the value can still be read programatically (which is not the case with `disabled`).